# google lyrics web scraper

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping

I want to create a bot which will return the lyrics of a desired song and apparently google is the best provider

so I need to scrape off the contents like this

[image]

but the problem is I need to click the 'Show more' button to get the complete lyrics

is it possible to do that without using selenium? because if I can press the button then it's just a matter of scraping the HTML using axios or something, having a complete webdriver seems like an overkill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using axios you don't have to "click" the button (the rest of the text is juste hide but present in the html response).
So you just need to take the response from axios and parse your html to get only the part you want

Comment: oof this is embarrassing I didn't properly inspect the whole page
but while we're on the topic, incase some resources are being fetched on pressing the button then how would you achieve scraping?

Comment: 3 ways : use a scraping engine that emulate user inputs like selenium, get the request that load the data in the page (in most cases this came form an API) or you can use a script that trigger the event onClick and handle the Dom changes to get your data (can be pretty tricky if the website use virtualDom)